# Use user interface from custom file manager (Total commander, Free Commander, etc) in file save box in browsers

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management

Is it possible to use the same user interface from a file manager as a replacement to the default on a browser (ie chrome), for example when downloading or saving a file from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

It's not practical.

These dialogs are provided by the OS. One could inject custom code into the OS to modify them, but it's *a lot* of work. You'd also have to rebuild them from scratch. All in all, it's not worth it.